# What does "units" mean in epiR package?

Tags: r, epidemiology

From [epiR manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/epiR/epiR.pdf) for ***epi.2by2*** function:

> units: multiplier for prevalence and incidence estimates.

In examples it is set to 100, `units=100`. What does it mean?

**Note:** I am working on ~5K case ~5K control data, no stratas, outcome vs exposure - 2by2 tables.

**Update:** This [PDF](http://www.medicalbiostatistics.com/prevalenceincidence.pdf) might be relevant.

Comment: I think this will become apparent if you set it to 1, then set it too 100, and compare the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can find the answer to this by digging into some of the examples:

> A study was conducted by Feychting et al (1998) comparing cancer
>   occurrence among the blind with occurrence among those who were not
>   blind but had severe visual impairment. From these data we calculate a
>   cancer rate of 136/22050 person-years among the blind compared with
>   1709/127650 person-years among those who were visually impaired but
>   not blind.

```
library(epiR)
dat <- as.table(matrix(c(136,22050,1709,127650), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
rval <- epi.2by2(dat = dat, method = "cohort.time", conf.level = 0.90, units = 1000,  homogeneity = "breslow.day", outcome = "as.columns")
summary(rval)$ARe.strata
```

> The incidence rate of cancer was 7.22 cases per 1000 person-years less
>   in the blind, compared with those who were not blind but had severe
>   visual impairment (90% CI 6.20 to 8.24 cases per 1000 person-years).
>   Confidence intervals for this attributable risk estimate are from
>   Rothman (2002, p 137).

Essentially, for many rate-based estimates in epidemiology, your estimate is multiplied by some number in order to get something like "Cases per X person-years", as these are often more intelligible than "Small Decimal per 1 person-day" or however else your data is estimated.

In this example, the units = 1000 yields an estimate of -7.22, which would be interpreted as 7.22 less cases per 1000 person-years. Changing units to equal 100 yields -0.72, which is interpreted as 0.72 less cases per 100 person-years.